# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on maven spring webapp

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm building a webapp using maven and Spring. I have a DTO in my service module and I want to use it in my web module, so, I've put the dependency with the service like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In my Controller I use it:

```
UserDTO u1 = new UserDTO(1,"User 1", "New User");
```

However, I'm getting a:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my/service/dto/UserDTO
my.web.controllers.Controller.home(Controller.java:38)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Don't know how to solve it. Maybe something is wrong with maven?

Comment: Do you understand what the error normally mean?

Comment: It means that, for some reason, the .class for UserDTO is not available when requested.

Comment: Should it be available?  Is the jar file part of the deployment?

Answer (score 0):

If you use springboot with multiple modules add repackage

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Tried to clean/full rebuild after the adding? Added to root module?

Comment: Look inside the packaged .jar or .war to see if you classes appear there?

Comment: Yes, I've cleaned and rebuild the full project. And my .class appears under the target folder.